# ElementNotVisibleException Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I trying to make a login with selenium on https://www.packtpub.com/

i trying this:

```
def setUp(self):

    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\_workspace\projects\Packtpub\chromedriver')
    self.driver.get("https://www.packtpub.com")
    time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!


def test_login(self):

    driver = self.driver
    driver.maximize_window()

    login1 = driver.find_element_by_id("email-wrapper")
    login1.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("my_login")
```

so return this error:

> ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible

I don't know why

Comment: Did you try with implicit wait in selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there are 2 elements with `id="email"` on page (try `driver.find_elements_by_id("email")` and you will see it). So you should try

```
driver.find_elements_by_id("email")[1].send_keys("my_login")
```